# demo maps for training pgRouting

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting

I'm very new to postgis and pgRouting but I'm using it for my thesys.
I need any map to train my self with routing and TSP problems in pgRouting, but on the Internet I found unworking links only!
Can anyone suggest me where to download these maps (rather in osm)? 
thanks a lot
Laura

Comment: What is the goal of your research? operational or theoretical?

Answer (score 5):

To try by yourself, you can check these links :

- http://workshop.pgrouting.org/
- http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/howto.html
- http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/
- http://www.carsonfarmer.com/?p=799

Comment: I didn't know the fourth link; I'll try!